# Is it possible to set default param value for the std::string_view?

Tags: c++, string-view

Is it safe to set an empty default value for the `std::string_view`?

```
void func(std::string_view arg = {} )
```

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be "safe"? What does "safe" mean?

Comment: Yes it's safe. But in case you try to access its characters using operator [] or stuff like .begin() then it's not safe.

Comment: why would .begin() not be safe? deferencing it wouldnt be safe

Comment: Safe, in itself, yes - in general? Depends on what you do with it afterwards.

Comment: The first thing I will do with it is check for emptiness. By the safe, I meant that string_view is not owning string

Answer (score 1):

It's allowed to create an empty `std::string_view` the same way it's allowed to create an empty `std::string` for example.

Of course, if your function intends to do some direct access operations (for example `std::string_view::front()` or `std::string_view::back()`), in that case, it will be necessary to check if the `std::string_view` is not empty beforehand (`std::string_view::empty()`).